# Adding a function Import in Entity Framework for a User Defined Table Tyle Stored procedure

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, datatable

I have created a stored procedure expecting a User Defined Table Type as Parameter.

As I want to use the stored procedure to be called via the Entity Framework I need to do a function Import.

But everytime I am trying to import the stored procedure I get the following Error:
`Die Funktion 'spMasterDataPropertiesUpdate' enthält den Parameter 'Data' am Parameterindex 1 mit dem Datentyp 'table type'. Dieser wird derzeit für die .NET Framework-Zielversion nicht unterstützt. Die Funktion wurde ausgeschlossen.`

In English:
`The 'spMasterDataPropertiesUpdate' function contains the parameter 'Data' at parameter index 1 with the data type 'table type'. This is currently not supported for. NET Framework version. The function was excluded.`

Apparently it is not working with Entity Framework 4.0. So what is a good workaround if I want to pass a table to a stored procedure using Entity Framework?

Comment: I would check to see if this feature is included in newer versions of EF- provided you can upgrade.